# Angular RouterUI $location.search() vs $stateParams

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

With the use of Angular UI Router - you can access parameters url using `$stateParams`. Additionally, the `$location` service also has a way to access URL parameters: `$location.search().param1`

I know that sometimes there is an advantage in using `$location.search()` to retrieve values in the URL. 
For example, when changing the URL without reloading state. Example snippet:

```
$state.current.reloadOnSearch = false;
$location.search('param1', 'new value').replace();
$timeout(function () {
    $state.current.reloadOnSearch = undefined;
});
```

In this case, the URL gets changed with new parameter `param1` - if I try to use `$stateParams.param1` - its undefined. Meaning, `$stateParams` doesn't know about that change. In such a scenario, I use `$location.search().param1` to get the updated value.

So as you can see, sometimes `$location.search()` has an advantage over `$stateParams`.

What are the disadvantages? Can't I just always use `$location.search()` and not use `$stateParams`? Is there any advantage in using `$stateParams`? What situations?

Comment: Well, most of the time, state params are not in $location.search. Like for example in a state with a URL like `/foos/:fooId`. I'm not sure why you even try to compare them. One is to get the parameters of the current state, one is to get the search parameters. Sometimes, and only sometimes, they happen to be the same thing.